# Incorrect Remainder in DX register after using DIV instruction

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

Trying to print the hex values as decimal but the DX register holds the wrong hex value. Here after the last div instruction DX should hold 0008h but the debugger shows it as 0004h. The quotient is wrong too.

```
assume cs:code
    code segment
    s:
    mov dx,0000h
    mov ax,0056h
    mov bx,000ah
    div bx
    push dx
    div bx
    push dx
    pop dx
    int 3h
    code ends
    end s
```

[image: Debugger snip]

Comment: You did notice that the first DIV placed the remainder in _DX_ and _DX_ was no longer zero?

Comment: Didn't get you, please elaborate

Comment: You correctly set DX to 0 before your first division, but didn't do that for your second division.

Comment: Noob mistake, can I downvote myself

Comment: Your first division does 32-bit divide by 16 bit divide DX:AX divided by BX. That ends up being in decimal 86/10 which is a quotient of 8 and remainder of 6. The quotient is in AX and the remainder is in DX. You then do another division of DX:AX divided by 0ah. DX:AX is 60008h.divided by 0ah (which is 393224/10 in decimal). That equals your value 999Ah in AX and 4 in DX. I suspect you intended to zero out _DX_ after the first division.